# Sums of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Given a multiset S of integers, when is
$$\sum_{s\in S}F_{n+s}=kF_{n+t}$$
for some integers k and t and all integers n?  $F_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci number.

Essentially, given a sum of Fibonacci numbers with fixed offsets, when can it be simplified to a multiple of a single Fibonacci number?  (Example: $F_{n-1}+2F_{n}+F_{n+2}=2F_{n+2}.$)

The generalization 
$$\sum_{s\in S}F_{n+s}=k_1F_{n+t_1}+k_2F_{n+t_2}$$
is also of interest to me, if there is a nice N&S condition for it.  And of course generalizations in other directions (any linear recurrence?) might be useful (though the special case of Fibonacci numbers is of special interest).

Comment: Highly relevant: [Zeckendorf family identities generalized](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4507).

Comment: Try looking at [Zeckendorf's system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem), maybe it will help.

Comment: There are two answers already referring to Zeckendorf's system, but  I am not sure if this helps or not check http://www1.math.american.edu/People/kalman/pdffiles/fibpaper.pdf somewhere down that discussion has something like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll consider the case where $k$ is rational. Define the polynomial
$$P(X)=\sum_{s\in S} X^s$$
and
$$Q = P = aX+b \pmod{X^2-X-1}$$
Then if
$$\sum_{s\in S} F_{n+s}=k F_{n+t}$$
we have
$$Q = kX^t \pmod{X^2-X-1}$$
$$Q = kF_{t+1} X+kF_t \pmod{X^2-X-1}$$
so $a/b$ is the ratio $F_{t+1}/F_t$.

Conversely if $a/b$ can be expressed as $F_{t+1}/F_t$ for some integer $t$, define $k=b/F_t$. Then the equation is satisfied. It's easy to see that $k$ and $t$ are unique.

The restriction to integer $k$ then follows, by checking whether $F_t$ divides $b$.

The generalization is trivially satisfied for all $P$ by taking $k_1=b$, $t_1=0$, $k_2=a$, $t_2=1$.

This is not specific to the Fibonacci sequence, any linear recurrence will do. Informally what the polynomial modulo $X^2-X-1$ represents is the "state" of the sequence. So if $Q$ transforms the state exactly like going forward $t$ steps would do, the sum will coincide with a translated sequence.